# Python/Pandas - remove not duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have DataFrame like this:

```
        product_id          dt  stock_qty
226870     2948259  2017-11-11     17.000
233645     2948259  2017-11-12     17.000
240572     2948260  2017-11-13      5.000
247452     2948260  2017-11-14      5.000
233644     2948260  2017-11-12      5.000
226869     2948260  2017-11-11      5.000
247451     2948262  2017-11-14     -2.000
226868     2948262  2017-11-11     -1.000  <- not duplicated
240571     2948262  2017-11-13     -2.000
240570     2948264  2017-11-13      5.488
233643     2948264  2017-11-12      5.488
244543     2948269  2017-11-11      2.500
247450     2948276  2017-11-14      3.250
226867     2948276  2017-11-11      3.250
```

I have to remove rows where `stock_qty` are different but `product_id` values are the same. So I should get DataFrame like this:

```
        product_id          dt  stock_qty
226870     2948259  2017-11-11     17.000
233645     2948259  2017-11-12     17.000
240572     2948260  2017-11-13      5.000
247452     2948260  2017-11-14      5.000
233644     2948260  2017-11-12      5.000
226869     2948260  2017-11-11      5.000
240570     2948264  2017-11-13      5.488
233643     2948264  2017-11-12      5.488
244543     2948269  2017-11-11      2.500
247450     2948276  2017-11-14      3.250
226867     2948276  2017-11-11      3.250
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for get all `product_id` values and then exclude them by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with another condition chained by `xor` `(^)`:

```
m1 = df['product_id'].isin(df.drop_duplicates('stock_qty', keep=False)['product_id'])
m2 = df.duplicated('product_id', keep=False)

df = df[m1 ^ m2]
print (df)
        product_id          dt  stock_qty
226870     2948259  2017-11-11     17.000
233645     2948259  2017-11-12     17.000
240572     2948260  2017-11-13      5.000
247452     2948260  2017-11-14      5.000
233644     2948260  2017-11-12      5.000
226869     2948260  2017-11-11      5.000
240570     2948264  2017-11-13      5.488
233643     2948264  2017-11-12      5.488
244543     2948269  2017-11-11      2.500
247450     2948276  2017-11-14      3.250
226867     2948276  2017-11-11      3.250
```

Detail:

```
print (m1)
226870    False
233645    False
240572    False
247452    False
233644    False
226869    False
247451     True
226868     True
240571     True
240570    False
233643    False
244543     True
247450    False
226867    False
Name: product_id, dtype: bool

print (m2)
226870     True
233645     True
240572     True
247452     True
233644     True
226869     True
247451     True
226868     True
240571     True
240570     True
233643     True
244543    False
247450     True
226867     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: But I need to exlude rows with product_id 2948262 at all because they have row which is not duplicate with other rows with the same product_id

Comment: And if I have one row with the same product_it this code will exclude it too but it shouldn't

Comment: I dont understand.  Can you change sample data with desired output? Or do you think if third product_id is unique, e.g. 123 then this row has to be removed? Thanks

Comment: I have edited quesition. I added row with product_id 2948269 and it doesn't have to dropped.

Comment: Please check it ;)

Answer (score 4):

@jezrael solution is optimal, but another way is using `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby(['product_id','stock_qty']).filter(lambda x: len(x)>1)
```

Output:

```
        product_id          dt  stock_qty
226870     2948259  2017-11-11     17.000
233645     2948259  2017-11-12     17.000
240572     2948260  2017-11-13      5.000
247452     2948260  2017-11-14      5.000
233644     2948260  2017-11-12      5.000
226869     2948260  2017-11-11      5.000
247451     2948262  2017-11-14     -2.000
240571     2948262  2017-11-13     -2.000
240570     2948264  2017-11-13      5.488
233643     2948264  2017-11-12      5.488
247450     2948276  2017-11-14      3.250
226867     2948276  2017-11-11      3.250
```

Comment: this will drop the duplicates but will keep any potential triplicates or more...

Answer (score 4):

By using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop(df.drop_duplicates(['stock_qty', 'product_id'], keep=False).index)
Out[797]: 
        product_id          dt  stock_qty
226870     2948259  2017-11-11     17.000
233645     2948259  2017-11-12     17.000
240572     2948260  2017-11-13      5.000
247452     2948260  2017-11-14      5.000
233644     2948260  2017-11-12      5.000
226869     2948260  2017-11-11      5.000
247451     2948262  2017-11-14     -2.000
240571     2948262  2017-11-13     -2.000
240570     2948264  2017-11-13      5.488
233643     2948264  2017-11-12      5.488
247450     2948276  2017-11-14      3.250
226867     2948276  2017-11-11      3.250
```

Answer (score 0):

With `loc[]` you can filter just the duplicated rows and assign to your original dataframe.

```
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['product_id','stock_qty'], keep=False)]
```

Also the `keep=False` parameter mark all the duplicated rows as True, if you want just the first or the last use `keep='first'` or `keep='last'`